# How to run and debug a snap application with GDB?

Tags: debugging, gdb, snapcraft

We have an open-source C++/Qt application which we recently also started to package and distribute as a snap (snapcraft). It's been a bumpy ride. Among numerous other issues some users have reported crashes (SIGSEGV) when running the application from the snap (including during startup), but we are at a loss about how to produce reasonable backtraces in these cases. If possible we want to avoid adding code or libraries for printing backtraces into the snaps.

**How to run and debug a snap application with GDB?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `snap run --gdb <snap_name>`. It requires sudo password though.